# Wrong output after implementing given equation

Tags: verilog

I am new to Verilog. While implementing this function:

```
data_out = [ [data_in / ( |data_in| + 1 ) ] + 1 ] / 2
```

I am not getting correct output. Can someone tell me how to write Verilog code to implement this function? I am sending my code and test bench. Please correct me where I am wrong.

```
module act_fun(data_out,data_in);
  input  [22:0] data_in;
  output [22:0] data_out;
  reg    [22:0] data_out;
  reg    [22:0] mod;
  reg    [22:0] mod1;
  reg    [22:0] mod2;

  always @(data_in)
  begin 
    mod      = data_in + 23'b1;
    mod1     = data_in/mod;
    mod2     = mod1 + 23'b1;
    data_out = mod2>>1'b1;
  end

endmodule
```

### testbench

```
module act_tst;
  // Inputs
  reg [22:0] data_in;
  // Outputs
  wire [22:0] data_out;

  // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
  act_fun uut (
    .data_out(data_out), 
    .data_in(data_in)
  );

  initial 
  begin
    data_in    = 23'b00000000000000000000000;
    #5 data_in = 23'b00000000000000000010000;
    #5 data_in = 23'b00000000000000001001100;
    #5 data_in = 23'b00000000000000111100010;
  end      
endmodule
```

### output:

```
data_out = 0000000000000000000000
5 data_out = 0000000000000000000000
5 data_out = 0000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Please do not double space the code and use spaces instead of tabs. It makes reading the question much easier, thanks.

Comment: sorry sir next time i will take care,sir solution  ????? how can i implement this equation in xilinx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at this in a wave form window or print more information on you internal mod variables you will notice that `mod1` never changes, always 0.

```
mod1     = data_in/mod;
```

I previously answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20592282/97073) regarding how the output from a multiply is expanded based on the input wordlengths. The same is true for Division.

`mod1` will never reach 1, i.e. is max value is + ve infinity / (+ve infinity + 1). you are performing an integer divide so the answer is always 0.

You need to decide how many fractional places you require and pad the numerator. The answer will then be fractional and you have to keep track of the binary point through out your calculations.

### Example

```
module act_fun(
  input      [22:0] data_in,
  output reg [22:0] data_out
);
  reg    [22:0] mod;
  reg    [22:0] mod1;
  reg    [22:0] mod2;

  always @(data_in) begin 
    mod      = data_in + 23'b1;
    mod1     = {data_in, 10'b0}/mod; //Adding 10 fractional bits
    mod2     = mod1 + 23'b1;
    data_out = mod2>>1'b1;
  end

endmodule
```

### Verification

For verification you might want to consider evaluating the equation (model) using reals and applying a tolerance relevant to the number of fractional bits you added.

```
real data_in_r
real data_out_r 
always @* begin
  data_out_r = (( data_in / ( (data_in+1 ))+1 ) / 2 ;
end
```

Comment: +1 for clear and concise answer. I did want to clarify your meaning in the first sentence, though. I believe when you said that `mod1` is "never set" you meant "never set to a non-zero value" rather than "the assignment to mod1 does not occur."

Comment: i got my mistake thanks but again one problem how to verify the output

Comment: @JoeHass thanks, I will update that sentence you are correct what is written is not strictly true, it is assigned a value it just happens to always be 0.